# difference of ml-auto and justify-content-end in bootstrap

Tags: html, css

thanks for attention and reading this.

what difference of ml-auto and justify-content-end in bootstrap?

[image]

[image]

i have used both classes, but they doing similar things, floating right, and which class i use does have any meaning?

Answer (score 1):

The Bootstrap class `ml-auto` sets `margin-left: auto!important`, whereas
`justify-content-end` sets `justify-content: flex-end!important`.

[`margin-left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-left) can set a left-hand margin for any type of element, offsetting it from the left of the prior element. It usually applies to the box model because of this, though note that it is tied to [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), so *can* lead to [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing). `auto` almost always sets a value of `0`, though there are a few exceptions depending on the type of layout:

> The left margin receives a share of the unused horizontal space, as determined mainly by the layout mode that is used. If the values of `margin-left` and `margin-right` are both auto, the calculated space is evenly distributed.

[`justify-content`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content) is specifically for [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), and `flex-end` merely aligns the target element (content) to the right-hand-side (end) of the container:

[image]

Comment: i am understand, thanks for comprehensive answer